# Webpack, datatable & yadcf

Tags: javascript, datatables, webpack, requirejs, yadcf

I'm trying to switch from a requirejs config to a webpack one and am having trouble to make yadcf work.

In my packages.json :

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.12",
    "datatables.net-bs": "^1.10.12",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "yadcf-npm": "^0.8.9"
  }
}
```

My webpack.config.js :

```
...
resolve: {
  alias: {
    ...
    datatables: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables'),
    datatablesBootstrap: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap'),
    yadcf: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/yadcf-npm/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js'),
  }
}
```

my script :

```
define(['jquery', 'datatablesBootstrap', 'yadcf'], function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        ...
        var myDatatable = dataTable = $('#elem').DataTable({
            ...
        });

        myDatatable.yadcf([
            ...
        ]);
    });
});
```

I keep having the same issue where yadcf is not defined

> Uncaught ReferenceError: yadcf is not defined(…)

Do you know what I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use yadcf v0.9.1 , since the support for AMD / CommonJS was added in this release and it should work with Webpack too, you can get it [from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yadcf) or [from github](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/releases/tag/0.9.1) or bower...

Comment: Oh my god I swear I tested with this version but I must have left yadcf-npm in my webpack config file when I did. This time I updated the webpack config as well and it worked ! Thank you sir.